# Validate fields only when a checkbox is true (ASP.NET-MVC3)

Tags: validation, data-annotations, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form where there are fields which are hidden by default and only visible if the user checks an "additional info" checkbox.
I want these fields to validate against dataannotation attributes (such as required, string length, match regex, etc) on BOTH client and serverside, but only IF the "additional info" checkbox is checked.

Is there a built in solution for this in dataannotations?

The best solution would be something that only modifies my viewmodel, but if I need to dirty my hands by writing custom code in the controller so be it.

I would want to be able to use things like ModelState.IsValid, so tampering with the modelstate is also an option if there is no other way.

Can you suggest some good solutions for this?

Comment: Found a solution? I'm having the same doubt!

Comment: I have found a way to build my VM in a way that the form parts can be switched, and I'll only need to reparse the form with a jquery.validation extension. I'll post my solution as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question. But there is a nice way to do this nowadays: [FoolProof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/).
For example, the `[RequiredIf]` attribute.